# Few things about form in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a form. I tried to change styling of checkbox and radio buttons using CSS, but with no luck. Finally I found some JS code that seems to be working. It changes styling of checkboxes, but doesn't change styling of radio buttons. Also the position of labels of checkboxes does not assign with checkboxes.

JS code:

```
$(function() {

    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
        var span = $('<span class="' + $(this).attr('type') + ' ' + $(this).attr('class') + '"></span>').click(doCheck).mousedown(doDown).mouseup(doUp);
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            span.addClass('checked');
        }
        $(this).wrap(span).hide();
    });

    function doCheck() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
            $(this).removeClass('checked');
            $(this).children().prop("checked", false);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('checked');
            $(this).children().prop("checked", true);
        }
    }

    function doDown() {
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    }

    function doUp() {
        $(this).removeClass('clicked');
    }
});
```

It doesn't seem to work perfectly in jsfiddle, but: http://jsfiddle.net/Sgn6n/1/

And here's the code I based my code on: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/xP2Ns/

Comment: To make the JS code style the radio buttons also, just add `input[type=radio]` to your `$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function()`.

Comment: Could you post a code? I don't know JS and actually I don't know how to add this stuff.

Comment: OK, there's one thing more... Now I can select several radio buttons, while I should select only one. The name of radio buttons in html code is the same for all four buttons, but still I can select more than one radio button.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know much JS either, but it might be caused by the function.